# Looking for the title of a book about a ships crew altering themselves as needed through nanomachines

Tags: story-identification, nanotechnology

I can't remember many details as I read the book 6-7 years ago, but I recall that the crew would lie down in a tub filled with nanomachines and be transformed when they awoke.

Comment: Around 6-7 years ago.

Comment: Were they traveling to a star that has creatures living on its surface?

Answer (score 3):

Hull Zero Three by Greg Bear has some of these themes - a crew modified by nanotech to adjust to whatever planet they arrive at (although it all goes pear shaped). Although that'
s fairly modern, written in 2010

Comment: Hull Zero Three does sound very interesting, sounds like fun even if it isnt what Im looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Charles Sheffield's ["Proteus"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1400576.Proteus_Unbound) series has form-change tanks used by workers in space to modify themselves to do specific tasks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The 2003 novel [*Star Dragon*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?24605) (Jan. 2005 [paperback](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?67604) edition) by [Mike Brotherton](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?7541) (reviewed [here](http://vastandcool.blogspot.com/2012/02/book-review-star-dragon-by-mike.html)) fits the description. In the following passage, the exobiologist Samuel Fisher is getting himself a "bodmod"; this is taking place aboard the *Karamojo*, a relativistic starship on a mission to the binary star [SS Cygni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_Cygni), hundreds of light-years from Earth.

> The nutrient bath squatted in an adjacent, tall-ceilinged chamber surrounded by organo-electric systems. Fisher stepped up the ladder to the top of the diamond rim. The fluid within bubbled darkly like a stew, a modern witch's cauldron.
>
> Fisher did not hesitate at the rim the way most people did. He rotated smoothly at the top and let his feet slip into the warm bath and immediately let go so his entire body could follow. Unlike most people, he did not hesitate to suck the oxygenated fluid into his mouth and lungs. There was no sense to hesitation, and a baser instinct overrode what he considered obsolete instincts against drowning. His alveoli switched into more efficient oxygen extraction with his very next heartbeat.
>
> In the warm, wet darkness thousands of viruses invaded his system. These were the agents of gene therapy that would inject themselves into his cells, dismantle his DNA at the introns, and insert or replace certain sequences that would govern the cellular operation of his new systems. More sophisticated **nanomachinery** would reconstruct the macrobiology into the forms he had selected. Still other devices, more sophisticated than viruses and more versatile than the machinery rebuilding his tissues, would isolate and protect his brain functions. Numbness struck his extremities and he knew that these were working. A warmth more vital than that of the bath grew within him: waste heat from the tiny machines and cellular changes. He was now trapped in his own morphing body several hours until the modifications would be complete.

Comment: Yeah, Stardragon was my first thought as well.  Interestingly I never thought of them as nanotech, but I suppose the biotech and "tiny machines" would certainly fit the bill.